# C- Indexing x,y,z coordinates in a 1D byte array

Tags: c, dataset, transformation, volume-rendering

I want to evaluate the values of the surface to implement a marching tetrahedron algorithm, but I don't understand how to work with .raw unformatted data.

After loading a .raw file with a volume dataset into a 1D byte array, what arithmetic transformation should be applied to get the value associated to X,Y,Z from it? This is the only way I know to load .raw files, could I create a 3D byte array instead of this? How?

```
int XDIM=256, YDIM=256, ZDIM=256;
const int size = XDIM*YDIM*ZDIM;
bool LoadVolumeFromFile(const char* fileName) {

    FILE *pFile = fopen(fileName,"rb");
   if(NULL == pFile) {
    return false;
   }

   GLubyte* pVolume=new GLubyte[size]; //<- here pVolume is a 1D byte array 
   fread(pVolume,sizeof(GLubyte),size,pFile);
   fclose(pFile);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you'd index the datum at (x, y, z) is:

```
pVolume[((x * 256) + y) * 256 + z]
```

Behind the scenes, this is what the C compiler does for you if you write:

```
GLuByte array[256][256][256];

array[x][y][z]
```

It only works that simply because C indexes from 0; if the language indexed from 1, you'd have to revise the calculation to achieve the net result obtained by subtracting one from each of x, y and z before doing the indexing.

---

#### Auxilliary Question

> Can you generalize the formula for arbitrary dimensions?

Given (where the numeric values don't really matter):

```
DIMx = 256
DIMy = 128
DIMz =  64
```

the datum at (x, y, z) in 1D array `pData` is found at:

```
pData[((x * DIMx) + y) * DIMy + z]
```

The value of DIMz serves primarily for validation: `0 <= z < DIMz` (using mathematical rather than C notation), and in parallel `0 <= x < DIMx; 0 <= y <= DIMy`.  The C notation for `z` is `0 <= z && z < DIMz`; repeat *mutatis mutandis* for `x` and `y`.

Comment: When using a 3D byte array would the fread be the same? size = XDIM*YDIM*ZDIM?

Comment: What happens when the grid is irregular (e.g. Z is 124 instead of 256), could you generalize the formula for arbitrary x,y,z please?